# Ember data related model does not display in template

Tags: ember-data

In the process of learning ember, and I'm not seeing where I'm going wrong. Any data I attempt to call from my related 'txplan' model will not render. I suspect my problem is with my route, and likely I'm doing something ridiculous. Any advice would be greatly appreciated. I do not currently see a call even attempted to the txplan API. Code / data is below

model/pat

```
const {
attr,
hasMany
} = DS;

export default DS.Model.extend({

  txplans: hasMany('txplan', { async: true }),

  pat: attr('number'),
  fname: attr('string'),
  lname: attr('string'),
  FullName: attr('string'),
  birthdate: attr('date'),
  email: attr('string'),
  hasins: attr('string'),
  estbalance: attr('number'),
  imagefolder: attr('string'),
  NextAppt: attr('date')

});
```

model/txplan

```
const {
attr,
belongsTo
} = DS;

export default DS.Model.extend({

  pat: belongsTo('pat', { async: true }),

  treatmentplannum: attr('number'),
  heading: attr('string'),
  dateTP: attr('date'),
  proccode: attr('string'),
  descript: attr('string'),
  fee: attr('number')


});
```

route/pat

```
import Route from '@ember/routing/route';

export default Route.extend({
  model() {
   return this.store.findAll('pat');
  },

 setupController(controller, model)
 { Ember.set(controller, 'pat', model) }

});
```

template (email will display, heading and fee will not. I've been trying both post.value and post.txplan.value.

```
{{#each pat as |post|}}
{{post.email}}
{{post.heading}}
{{post.txplan.fee}}
{{/each}}
```

Data/pat

```
{"status":200,"error":null,"pats":
[{"id":1,"pat":1,"fname":"Test","lname":"User","FullName":"Test 
User","birthdate":"1980-11-22,"email":"testuser@test.com","hasins":"I","estbalance":0,
"imagefolder":"TestUser1","NextAppt":null}
```

Data/txplan

```
{"status":200,"error":null,"txplan":
[{"id":1,"treatplannum":3,"pat":1,"heading":"Active",
"dateTP":"2018-02-23","proccode":"T4528","descript":"Amalgam-1 
Surf","Fee":70,"priority":0}
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe the issue was related to the structure of my data. I was able to resolve this by using RSVP in my route and passing the same parameter to each model like so:

```
model(params) {
  return Ember.RSVP.hash({
  pat: this.store.query('pat', {pat: params.pat}),
  txplan: this.store.query('txplan', {pat: params.pat})
  })
}
```